# Stackoverflow error on Jenkins plugin manager page

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, jenkins, stack-trace

I am getting stack overflow error on Jenkins 1.594 (installed on Ubuntu 12.1) plugin manager's **Update** and Available plug ins page. Please find below stack trace. Although I can see desired pages below this error. Could you please help me to get rid of this error.

Stack trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.594.jar!/hudson/PluginManager/table.jelly:74:52: <j:forEach> java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:735)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$3.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:183)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.594.jar!/hudson/PluginManager/table.jelly:74:52: <j:forEach> java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.WhenTag.doTag(WhenTag.java:46)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:813)
    at hudson.util.TextFile.exists(TextFile.java:57)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.getData(UpdateSite.java:271)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.getPlugin(UpdateSite.java:331)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.getPlugin(UpdateCenter.java:332)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin.getNeededDependencies(UpdateSite.java:684)
    at
```

Comment: I'm getting the same :/

Comment: same issue have been reported https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36361 people have commented that manual installation of Subversion plugin solved their issue. I am hesitant to try it on production environment. :(